# Python Framework that support MongoDB out of the box?

Tags: python, mongodb, frameworks

I'd like to exercise MongoDB in a real world project so I'm wondering what are the Python frameworks that support MongoDB as the main database out of the box (and are well documented)?

Comment: Just my opinion, but "out of the box" is overrated.

Comment: The FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) #4 suggests that asking for suggestions about software libraries is off topic.

Answer (score 5):

If you're talking Web-Frameworks there's [Tornado](http://codevoyeur.com/Downloads/Presentations/PHL-Mongo-Philly-Tornado-2011.pdf) or [Mongo-kit in Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/mongokit/) or [Flask-PyMongo](http://flask-pymongo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) that have great support for MongoDB, but at the end of the day it's all easily pluggable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "out of the box" but I have successfully used MongoDB with Tornado web server in a number of projects.

You can very easily interface with MongoDB using several libraries. My favorites are:

1. PyMongo: http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.2/
2. Mongoengine: http://mongoengine.org/

IMO Mongonegine is an excellent tool for communicating to Mongo through Python and it is relatively well documented. I particularly like the fact that Mongoengine provides concrete examples in the documentation (which is really nice for a beginner).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [django-mongokit](https://github.com/peterbe/django-mongokit.git) as excellent framework for your project. It bridges Django to MongoDB with the MongoKit ODM (Object Document Mapper).

As Django is most widely and successfully used in many projects, which has big community support and lots of packages are available that can be easily implement in the project.

We had successfully implemented it in our project which is available at [github](https://github.com/gnowledge/gstudio).